# Scope of Multiple For each loops in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with below data.

```
Category      | Amount    | Daily Charges | Misc Charges |  Vendor Charges
------------  |-----------| --------------|--------------|-------------------
Daily Charges |500,000.00 |               |              |       
--------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------------
Misc Charges  | 500.00    |               |              |       
--------------|-----------| --------------|--------------|-------------------
Vendor Charges| 50,000.00 |               |              |
```

I need to fill column 3 (Daily Charges) , column 4 (Misc Charges) and column 5(Vendor Charges) as below using macros.

```
Category      | Amount    | Daily Charges | Misc Charges |  Vendor Charges
------------  |-----------| --------------|--------------|-------------------
Daily Charges |500,000.00 | 500,000.00    |     0        |       0
--------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------------
Misc Charges  | 500.00    |     0         | ₹ 500.00     |       0
--------------|-----------| --------------|--------------|-------------------
Vendor Charges| 50,000.00 |     0         |      0       | 50,000.00
```

**Please help.**

I tried the below macro function but i'm unable to exit correctly from the scope of a for each loop .

```
Sub LoopInsert()

Dim tgt, final, rng, val, cell, cell2, cell3 As Range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set val = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set tgt = ActiveSheet.Range("C2", ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown))


For Each cell In rng
   For Each cell2 In val

    If cell.Value = "Daily Charges" Then
     Exit For
       For Each cell3 In tgt
        cell3.Value = cell2.Value
        Exit For
        Next
     Else
     For Each cell3 In tgt
        cell3.Value = 0
        Exit For
        Next
    End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a macro for this.
You can do this with formulas

```
=IF($C$1 = A2, B2, 0)
=IF($D$1 = A2, B2, 0)
=IF($E$1=A2, B2, 0)
```

Paste them in C2, D2, E2 and then copy 
the formulas for the rest of the cells

Or as YowE3K points out you can use
=IF(C$1=$A2,$B2,0) in cell C2, and copied to all the other cells (i.e. C2:E4)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

sticking to VBA you can simplify your code and reduce running time

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopInsert()
    Dim catColumnRng As Range, catRowRng As Range, colRng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set catColumnRng = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| store all "Category" not empty cells in column A from row 2 downwards
        Set catRowRng = .Range("C1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| store all "Category" not empty cells in row 1 from column 3 rightwards

        For Each cell In catColumnRng '<--| loop through column A "Category" cells
            Set colRng = catRowRng.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| try finding corresponding text in row 1 "Category" cells
            If Not colRng Is Nothing Then .Cells(cell.Row, colRng.Column).Value = cell.Offset(, 1) '<--| if found then place the value
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```